# Algorithms for 2FA over HTTPS?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, challenge-response

I'm developing an Authenticator App for use towards my own API. I know about the TOTP standard RFC 6238 and the HOTP variant. Though I would prefer to use a public/private key based solution (by only storing the public key on the server).

What are some more or less standardized alternatives?

Is a home invented challenge response scheme with a public/private key pair subject to attacks (in the context of a secure HTTPS channel)?

Answer (score 1):

If you - for whatever reason - preferred a challenge response protocol that used asymmetric cryptography, you may want to take a look at the [work of the FIDO alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDO_Alliance).

This seems however to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). It's not clear why welldefined, secure methods for second factor usage are out of scope for you. Also, as a sidenote: Please [do *NOT* roll you own crypto!](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

The gist of the linked QA: You are almost 100% guaranteed to make a mistake that can later be exploited.

Comment: With public/private keys I could extend solution to include signing and public keys are less security sensitive in the back-end. FIDO alliance is good input, though it looks massive. I was hoping for "checkout RFC XYZ".